# Use external display only with MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, preferences, displayport, display

I have a Mid 2010 MacBook. Is it possible to make the external display into the only one, so that I can close the lid and keep working on my MacBook with an external keyboard/mouse and monitor?

Comment: Make sure to keep the lid open while the computer is turned on. The machine produces heat that will be kept insides if lid is closed. May damage your display!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. It usually "just works," but if you're having trouble, Apple has detailed instructions:

[Apple Portables: How to use your computer in closed clamshell (display closed) mode with an external display](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3131)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I close the lid, wake it up with my bluetooth mouse/keyboard, and the external monitor turns on as the secondary display. I'm running 10.7.4 (latest) on a 2011 MBA. If I make the external monitor primary before closing the lid, some windows still remain on the internal screen even after the computer wakes up. I want the ext display to be the *only* one. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible (I use mine like this al the time).  All you need to do is ensure that the external power supply is plugged in.

If you intend on using this setup all the time, ensure you occasionally (say once a month), unplug the external power supply and use the battery.